Split text to files between regular repeating text strings using terminal
I have several blocks of text between regular intervals that I am trying to use shell to parse into separate files.
The file resembles this format:
<Line delimiter>
The lines of text to extract
<Line delimiter>
Other lines that are to be extracted but
also have an unpredictable length
<Line delimiter>
...
...
<Line delimiter>
and so forth

I was attempting a Split command and grepping between lines as:
for line in $(grep -n 'Line Delimiter' target.txt | cut -d ':' -f 1); do split -l $line target.txt  ; done 

With also, this with a head | tail pipe as what appeared to be one of the eloquent solutions seen in this example.  I have searched it out a little more, with a few other attempts but I feel like this should be relatively easy but accomplishing this feat for more than 1 iteration is proving difficult.
Any help thanks in advance.

What OS? On macOS (and maybe others), the split command has a -p (pattern) option, so split -p 'Line delimiter' target.txt should do everything you need. On other systems, you may be able to use csplit (context split).

Assuming a more conventional seperator, maybe something like awk 'BEGIN{RS="----------"}{if ($0 ~ /srchString/) {print $0 > "/path/to/file"++i}; close("/path/to/file"i) }' inputFile will make numbered  files. See the awk tutorial for what this means. Good luck.

trivial example hopefully be helpful
$ cat input.txt
<Line delimiter>
The lines of text to extract
<Line delimiter>
Other lines that are to be extracted but
also have an unpredictable length
<Line delimiter>
these should also go...
into another file ...
<Line delimiter>
and so forth
$
$ #repeat the split as many times as the match is made
$ csplit -q input.txt '/<Line delimiter>/' '{*}'
$
$ # file xx00 is empty as the first occurence of <Line delimiter> is line 1   
$ cat xx01
<Line delimiter>
The lines of text to extract
$ cat xx02
<Line delimiter>
Other lines that are to be extracted but
also have an unpredictable length
$ cat xx03
<Line delimiter>
these should also go...
into another file ...
$ cat xx04
<Line delimiter>
and so forth

check out the csplit manpage for additional info.

Hey thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Also shout out to @Gairfowl for pointing it out earlier.
